# PYTHON - .lower()

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.6, python-idle

Here's the code;

```
names = ('laia')
good = ('good', 'great', 'beautiful')

name = raw_input ("What's your name?").lower()

if (name.split() or ('',))[0].lower() in names:   
name1 = raw_input("Do you know Laia is my name?").lower()
```

Later on when I print the name, so if you enter your name as 'bob' it comes out as 'bob' but I'd like it like this 'Bob' so capitalised.

Comment: Why not [RTFM](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)?

Comment: Warning: `('laia')` is just the string `'laia'`. You seem to already know what to do to fix that, judging by the `('',)`, unless you just copy-pasted that from someone else's code.

Comment: I made the code but it caught me out a bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.title()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) instead of [`.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.capitalize()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize). It is used to convert the first letter of a string into an uppercase letter.